# VBA Code to Alert Against Expired Material Assistance

Tags: vba, popup

I am trying to create a popup window as soon as I open my excel file.

The excel workbook that I have has multiple sheets.

One of the sheets is titled "Inventory".

As shown in the image below, there is a column in the Inventory tab that is titled "Days Until Expiration".

I want to have my excel file display a pop up when opening the workbook. This popup will check the "Days Until Expiration" column in the "Inventory" tab and say something like "____ material" (from the 'Type' Column) "has ____" days until expiration.

This will only happen if the "Days Until Expiration" value is in between 0 and 14 days.

If the number is negative in the "Days Until Expiration" column, I want the message pop up to say "___ material has expired".

Shown below is what I have so far. I have created a workbook_open() event and this code is in my "ThisWorkbook" code tab.

I am also getting an error when I run what I have below, specifically saying:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()



Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rngUsed As Range, rngExpirationColumn As Range, rngCell As Range
        Dim strExpirationMessage As String

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Inventory")
        Set rngUsed = ws.UsedRange
        Set rngExpirationColumn = Intersect(ws.Columns(4), rngUsed)

        For Each rngCell In rngExpirationColumn.Cells
            If Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2) >= 14 Then
                If Len(strExpirationMessage) = 0 Then
                    strExpirationMessage = rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Value2 & " material has " & (Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2)) & " days left before expiration"
                Else
                    strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & Chr(13) & rngCell.Offset(0, -3).Value2 & " material has " & (Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2)) & " days left before expiration"
                End If
            End If
        Next

        MsgBox strExpirationMessage

End Sub
```

[image: Excel file showing columns]

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: I'd start by adding a test for `IsDate(rngCell.Value2)`. My *guess* is that you have empty cells in your `ws.UsedRange`.

Comment: The error is occurring at "If Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2) >= 14 Then"

Comment: Can you show us at least one row with data? My *guess* is that you are trying to convert the value of "Days Until Expiration" (which is probably just a number) into a Date, and that is causing the issue. If that is the case, your logic to validate `If Date - CDate(rngCell.Value2) >= 14 Then` should probably only be `If rngCell.Value2 >= 14 Then` (and even that logic does not satisfy your request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm posting this answer based on your request and with some assumptions, as follows:

- You want to check the data for column "Days Until Expiration" (as per your request)
- You want to grab the data from column "Type" to add on the popup (as per your request)
- You want one message if the Expiration Days is between 0 and 14
- You want another message if the Expiration Days is less than 0
- The value on column "Days Until Expiration" is actually a number (this is an assumption, since no data was provided)
- I'm assuming "Days Until Expiration" is merged into two rows (per screenshot)
- I'm assuming your data is directly below the rows from your screenshot, so probably your actual data starts on Row 4

Here is the code (tested based on assumptions above, due to lack of actual data to reproduce the scenario):

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strExpirationMessage As String
    Dim rngExpirationCell As Range, rngTypeCell As Range
    Dim lngRow As Long, lngExpirationCol As Long, lngTypeCol As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Inventory")
    Set rngExpirationCell = ws.UsedRange.Find(What:="Days Until Expiration", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    Set rngTypeCell = ws.UsedRange.Find(What:="Type", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rngExpirationCell Is Nothing And Not rngTypeCell Is Nothing Then
        lngExpirationCol = rngExpirationCell.Column
        lngTypeCol = rngTypeCell.Column

        For lngRow = rngExpirationCell.row + 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            With ws.Cells(lngRow, lngExpirationCol)

                If 0 <= .Value And .Value <= 14 Then
                    strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has " & .Value & " days left before expiration" & vbCrLf
                ElseIf .Value < 0 Then
                    strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has expired" & vbCrLf
                End If

            End With
        Next

        strExpirationMessage = Left(strExpirationMessage, Len(strExpirationMessage) - 2) 'to remove trailing vbCrLf
        MsgBox strExpirationMessage

    End If

End Sub
```

**Important Notes:**

- I've modified part of your logic, by eliminating some variables and using others instead.
- I'm not working with range objects, but rather with specified cells
- I'm performing a dynamic search for the desired Columns "Days Until Expiration" and "Type", instead of working with fixed column and with offsets, to allow you to change the columns position in future without changing the code.
- I'm assuming "Days Until Expiration" is merged into two rows (per screenshot) and this is why I'm using `rngExpirationCell.row + 2` in the `For` loop. If you have anything different than that, the code might need changes.

I hope this suits your needs. Let me know of any issues or concerns.
If this post answers your question, please Accept it by clicking on the Check mark on the left of it.

**Update:**
Based on the issues you found, below are two alternate solutions for the `For` loop that you could use. Everything else should be exactly the same. Just replace the `For` loop with either of the logic below and you should be good to go

Assuming you want to leave the logic once you found an Empty cell:

```
For lngRow = rngExpirationCell.row + 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With ws.Cells(lngRow, lngExpirationCol)
        If IsEmpty(.Value) Then Exit For    'Will leave the For loop once an Empty cell is found

        If 0 <= .Value And .Value <= 14 Then
            strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has " & .Value & " days left before expiration" & vbCrLf
        ElseIf .Value < 0 Then
            strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has expired" & vbCrLf
        End If

    End With
Next
```

Assuming you want to skip the evaluation for the Empty cells, but continue checking the cells until the end of the Used Range:

```
For lngRow = rngExpirationCell.row + 2 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    With ws.Cells(lngRow, lngExpirationCol)
        If Not IsEmpty(.Value) Then    'Will skip empty cells but continuing validation until the end of the Used Range
            If 0 <= .Value And .Value <= 14 Then
                strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has " & .Value & " days left before expiration" & vbCrLf
            ElseIf .Value < 0 Then
                strExpirationMessage = strExpirationMessage & ws.Cells(lngRow, lngTypeCol).Value & " material has expired" & vbCrLf
            End If
        End If

    End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much the code works great and all your assumptions were correct! There is only one issue. It seems to be recognizing all the unfilled rows. For example, for all the rows under the last filled row, the code recognizes them as empty and outputs "material has  days left before expiration". This runs infinitely until the very last row of the excel page and it is causing the program to take a few minutes to run. It also fills up the message prompt with 20 messages of "material has  days left before expiration". What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Do you have Empty Cells and after it more cells with values, or if I found an empty cell I should assume I've reached the end of the table? I'm asking this because if the empty cells determine the end of the table I can Exit the For loop, otherwise I would have to just skip the validation for those cells, so depending on your answer, the logic would be different

Comment: If you find an empty cell you should assume you have reached the end of the table.

Comment: Please see my update. I've added two alternatives for your code. Follow the first approach for your current issue (leave For loop once you find an Empty cell). In case you need it in the future, you also have an alternative for the second approach (continuing evaluation but skip empty cells)